# Computing the spherical mean and showing it satisfies PDE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Compute the [spherical mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_mean) of the function $h : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ with
$$
 h(x,y,z) = x
$$
and show that it satisfies the differential equation
$$
 u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r} u_r = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}
$$
(note that the spherical mean of a function is a function of some fixed point and a radius).

Comment: Sounds incredible to me that $\int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta \mathrm d \theta = -2$ . Furthermore, the notation $M_h$ together with $M_{rr}$ and even worse $M_{xx} + M_{yy} + \cdots$ together with $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T$ and $(x + ry) \mathrm d y\;$ is at least confusing. Really don't understand much of your question anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I rewrote everything and deleted the calculations, hoping everything is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by epimorphic's comment, I decided to derive the formula to see what happens. I believe the question should be phrased as: say with slightly abuse of notation let us denote $\vec{x} = (x,y,z)$ and $r>0$ be a fixed radius, then

> Let $u(\vec{x},r)$ be the spherical mean of $h:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$:
>   $$u(\vec{x},r) := \frac{1}{\omega_{2}(r)}\int_{\partial B(\vec{x},r)} h(\vec{y})\,dS(\vec{y}), \tag{1}$$
>   the problem wants to investigate whether or not
>   $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} u(\vec{x},r) + \frac{2}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} u(\vec{x},r) = \Delta_{\vec{x}}u(\vec{x},r):= \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)u(\vec{x},r).$$

Using the second formula the wikipedia entry of spherical mean provides:
$$u(\vec{x},r) = \frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)}\int_{\|\vec{y}\|=1} \! h(\vec{x}+r\vec{y}) \, dS(\vec{y}).$$
This formula gives us an easier form to compute $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$ than the first, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(\vec{x},r) = \frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)}\int_{\|\vec{y}\|=1} \! \nabla_{\vec{x}} \,h(\vec{x}+r\vec{y}) \cdot \vec{y}\, dS(\vec{y}). 
$$
Also due to the unit sphere nature of the formula, we can exploit the divergence theorem on this formula: change of the derivative w.r.t. $\vec{y}$ and use the fact that $\vec{y}$ is the exterior unit vector normal to the unit sphere $\{\|y\|=1\}$.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(\vec{x},r) =\frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)}\int_{\|\vec{y}\|=1} \! \frac{1}{r}\nabla_{\vec{y}} \,h(\vec{x}+r\vec{y}) \cdot \vec{y}\, dS(\vec{y})
\\
= \frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)}\int_{\|\vec{y}\|<1} \! \frac{1}{r}\Delta_{\vec{y}} \,h(\vec{x}+r\vec{y})\,d\vec{y}
\\
= \frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)}\int_{\|\vec{y}\|<1} \! r\Delta_{\vec{x}} \,h(\vec{x}+r\vec{y})\,d\vec{y}.
$$
Now use the spherical shell integration formula again in Evans's Appendix C.3 (see also his application in 2.2.2):
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(\vec{x},r) =\frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)}r\Delta_{\vec{x}} \frac{1}{r^3}
\int_{\|\vec{y}\|<r} h(\vec{x}+ \vec{y})\,d\vec{y}
\\
=\frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)r^2}\Delta_{\vec{x}}
\int^r_0\left(\int_{\partial B(\vec{x},s)} h(\vec{y}')\,dS(\vec{y}')\right)ds.
$$
Comparing with (1) we have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(\vec{x},r) 
=\frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{\vec{x}}
\int^r_0 s^2\left(\frac{1}{\omega_{2}(1)s^2}\int_{\partial B(\vec{x},s)} h(\vec{y}')\,dS(\vec{y}')\right)ds
\\
= \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{\vec{x}}\int^r_0 s^2 u(\vec{x},s)\,ds. 
$$
This implies
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(\vec{x},r) \right)
= \Delta_{\vec{x}} (r^2 u(\vec{x},r)),
$$
which reduces to
$$
r^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}u(\vec{x},r) + 2r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}u(\vec{x},r) = r^2 \Delta_{\vec{x}}  u(\vec{x},r),
$$
the same formula in the question above.

Answer (score 3):

With $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $r>0$, let us write
$$
M(x,r) = \frac1{4\pi}\int_{S^2}h(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi,
$$
where the integral is taken over the two dimensional unit sphere $S^2$.
Then the Laplacian of $M$ with respect to $x$ is
$$
\Delta_x M(x,r) = \frac1{4\pi}\int_{S^2} \Delta_x h(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi
= \frac1{4\pi}\int_{S^2} \Delta h(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi.
$$
Further, using the formula for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates, we have
$$
\Delta_x M(x,r) = \frac1{4\pi}\int_{S^2} (\partial_r^2+\frac2r\partial_r+\Delta_{S_r(x)}) h(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi ,
$$
where $\Delta_{S_r(x)}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator associated to the sphere of radius $r$ centred at $x$.
Finally, observing that the Laplace-Beltrami term integrates to zero, and taking the radial derivative operators outside the integral, we get the desired result. Note that all manipulations are justified if $h$ is a $C^2$ function in the region under consideration.

An alternative way, that avoids the explicit mention of the Laplace-Beltrami operator is to establish that the Laplace operator commutes with spherical mean, in the sense that 
$$
\int_{S^2} \Delta h(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi = \int_{S^2} \Delta g(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi,
$$
where
$$
g(y) = \frac1{4\pi}\int_{S^2} h(x+r\xi)\,\mathrm{d}^2\xi,
\qquad \textrm{for all}\quad y\in S_r(x).
$$

Comment: yes. But how does the spherical mean look like as a function of some point and r?

Comment: @Stefan Spherical mean averages out the polar and azimuth angle, therefore the mean is invariant on the angular variables (radially symmetric), which leads to the partial derivatives w.r.t. those two variables zero. As a result, the Laplacian ( the right hand side in your equation) only relies on the first term the link timur gave, and it reduces to what your equation's left hand side.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Does that apply here though? What you say would certainly be true if $u$ were a spherically symmetric function $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$, in which case $(x,y,z)$ and $(r,\theta,\phi)$ would be understood to be dependent coordinates. However, the spherical mean is a function of the center of the sphere _and_ the radius of the sphere. The domain is a _four_-dimensional manifold, and $x,y,z,r$ are all independent here.

Comment: @epimorphic: It is understood that the spherical mean $u$ is a function of $r=r(x,y,z)$, i.e., given $r>0$, you first compute the average of $h$ over the sphere of radius $r$, and then assign this value to $u$, whose value is constant on the said sphere.

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ is the coordinate of the center of the sphere, and not that of some point on the sphere.

Comment: @epimorphic I was wrong and thinking too naively w/o paper and pencil, thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao No problem, and to be honest, the question still needs a lot of work to improve the notational clarity so it's really not your fault if you misunderstood. And a correction to my first comment: "if $u$ were a spherically symmetric function $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$" should read "if $u$ were a spherically symmetric function $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$". Too late to fix now :/

Comment: @epimorphic: I think I misunderstood the question. Please see the update.

Comment: @epimorphic Yes, I rephrased the question and answered it myself. Greatly appreciate the comment again.

Answer (score 1):

Here we assume that the center of the ball with radius $r$ is at $(r=0,\theta=0,\phi=0)$. The spherical mean of $h(x,y,z)=x$ is given by:

$$\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^{\pi}rd\theta \int_0^{2\pi}r\sin\theta d\phi[r \sin\theta\cos\phi]=\frac{r^3}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} \cos\phi d\phi=0$$

Of course $u=0$ satisfies the homogeneous PDE:
$$u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r} u_r = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}$$

Now we assume that the center of the ball with radius $r$ is at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

So that $\vec R=(x,y,z)=(x',y',z')+(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.  We now set $x'=r \sin\theta\cos\phi,y'=r \sin\theta\sin\phi,z'=r \cos\theta$.

The spherical mean of $h(x,y,z)=x=x_0+x'=x_0+r \sin\theta\cos\phi$ is given by $I_1+I_2$. where

$$I_1=\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^{\pi}rd\theta \int_0^{2\pi}r\sin\theta d\phi[r \sin\theta\cos\phi]=\frac{r^3}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} \cos\phi d\phi=0$$

$$I_2=\frac{x_0}{4\pi r^2}\int_0^{\pi}rd\theta \int_0^{2\pi}r\sin\theta d\phi=x_0$$

Of course $u=0+x_0=\text{constant}$ satisfies the homogeneous PDE:
$$u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r} u_r = u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}$$

Comment: I think your answer is closer, but you assumed that the center of the sphere is at the origin, whereas the asker wants to know the case where the center $(x,y,z)$ is an arbitrary point in $\mathbb R^3$. Should be a quick fix. (And for the record, I didn't downvote this answer.)

Comment: @epimorphic Thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: Very belated injection after I found this while browsing .Obviously if the ball is at the origin the spherical mean is zero. If the ball is translated in the x-direction by an amount dx, then the value at every point on its surface increases by dx and so does the spherical mean.